# Laravel 8 Product Ajax Search Issue

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

We are using Laravel 8 for ecommerce. The built in search queries in Product categories, tags, product name, sku and brands. And its buffering so much for result to be appeared. And after appearing the result its being querying again automatically. And search result does not stay, if I put a space after search keyword then its going to appear the exact result.

After pressing backspace it starting a unlimited loop and the site stuck.

I have paste the full code for search here:

**Ajax Search Function:**

```
$('#search').on('keyup input change', function(){
                search();
            });
 
            $('#search').on('focus', function(){
                search();
            });
 
            function search(){
                var searchKey = $('#search').val();
                if(searchKey.length > 0){
                    $('body').addClass("typed-search-box-shown");
 
                    $('.typed-search-box').removeClass('d-none');
                    $('.search-preloader').removeClass('d-none');
                    $.post('{{ route('search.ajax') }}', { _token: AIZ.data.csrf, search:searchKey}, function(data){
                        if(data == '0'){
                            // $('.typed-search-box').addClass('d-none');
                            $('#search-content').html(null);
                            $('.typed-search-box .search-nothing').removeClass('d-none').html('Sorry, nothing found for <strong>"'+searchKey+'"</strong>');
                            $('.search-preloader').addClass('d-none');
 
                        }
                        else{
                            $('.typed-search-box .search-nothing').addClass('d-none').html(null);
                            $('#search-content').html(data);
                            $('.search-preloader').addClass('d-none');
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('.typed-search-box').addClass('d-none');
                    $('body').removeClass("typed-search-box-shown");
                }
            }
```

**Search Controller:**

```
public function ajax_search(Request $request)
        {
            $keywords = array();
            $products = Product::where('published', 1)->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
            foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                foreach (explode(',',$product->name) as $key => $tag) {
                    if(stripos($tag, $request->search) !== false){
                        if(sizeof($keywords) > 4){
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            if(!in_array(strtolower($tag), $keywords)){
                                array_push($keywords, strtolower($tag));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            $products = filter_products(Product::query());
    
            $products = $products->where('published', 1)
                            ->where(function ($q) use($request) {
                                $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%');
                            })
                        ->get();
    
            // $categories = Category::where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get()->take(3);
    
            // $shops = Shop::whereIn('user_id', verified_sellers_id())->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get()->take(3);
    
        

    if(sizeof($keywords)>0 || sizeof($products)>0){
                return view('frontend.partials.search_content', compact('products', 'keywords'));
            }
            return '0';
            }
```

Comment: This question is not dependent on Laravel. I think it better for you to use one of the existing plugins. i.e https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/